# Dose Marshal obj would be moved when call unmanaged code in managed code

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have a project which contains managed/unmanaged code.

managed code: C#---handle business logic

managed code: C++-- as an adapter between C# and C(unmanaged code)

unmanaged code: c/c++---handle Encode/Decode logic

So there're lots of [marshal operation], my code as below:

```
void fun(ManagedObject^ managedObj)
{
marshal_contex^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
const char* str = context->marshal_as<const char*>(managedObj->stringField);
//then call the c function,pass the str param to it
c_fun((u_char *)str);
}
```

ps: when i enable **fullpageheap** validation, the `c_fun` will throw a `Violate read exception`, then I check the dump file, the "str" points to an invalid address.

I don't know why? Is it a problem of fullpageheap? Or the Marshal Object be moved, but by whom?

Comment: The code is fundamentally wrong, you are supposed to call `delete context;` after the c_fun() call.  If you don't then the context can technically be garbage collected, which would make *str* invalid.  More likely is that you just have a standard case of unmanaged heap corruption.

Comment: @Hans Passant,when context be garbage collected the "str" would not be free? This is not the advantage of "marshal_context".please tell me more detail,Thanks

Comment: I found another topic answer by you, you said no need to deleted context. @Hans

Comment: Doubtful.  Google "c++/cli stack semantics" to learn how to do this properly.